# How can I hide calculated values in Pine Editor?

Tags: pine-script

I've altered a Bollinger band / EMA tool and I'm happy with the results, but I don't want to display some of the numerical outputs in the outputs line.  I'm new, so unfortunately I don't know what to try first!  Can somebody offer a suggestion on how to hide the unwanted values?  Thanks so much in advance!

[How can I hide the X'd out values?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THAlF.png)

The value I really want to display is the result of the PLOTCHAR line.

```
Length1 = input(8, minval=1)
Length2 = input(12, minval=1)
Length3 = input(26, minval=1)
xPrice = close
xEMA1 = ema(xPrice, Length1)
xEMA2 = ema(xPrice, Length2)
xEMA3 = ema(xPrice, Length3)
plot(xEMA1, color=#00FFFF, linewidth=3, transp=20,  title="4EMA 8")
plot(xEMA2, color=#FF00FF, linewidth=3, transp=20,  title="4EMA 12")
plot(xEMA3, color=#FF9800, linewidth=3, transp=20,  title="4EMA 26")

length = input(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = sma(src, length)
dev = mult * stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
plot(basis, title="median", color=white)
p1 = plot(upper, title="upper", color=white)
p2 = plot(lower, title="lower", color=white)
plotchar(dev*10000/close, title="Price Deviation Pct.", char="", location=location.top)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If you have a plot, its value will be there.

There is a way to hide the indicator values but that would hide all of them.

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much for your input.  As a follow-up, I worked around it by moving the output to first in the series rather than being the last.  So, all the outputs still show up but the one that most interests me shows up first.  It's kinda a caveman solution but it worked.  I really just needed it to be further left, so that accomplished the purpose.  Thank you once again for taking time to reply!